# can't run sty on consolecommand "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sty'"

Tags: python, import, module, pixel

I'm trying to create a programm that displays pixels of varying shade of grey on console command

I'm testing if the commands works so i try a simple:

```
from sty import bg, rs      

val = 0

qui = bg(val, val, val) + ' ' + bg.rs

print(f"\033[{0};{0}H{qui}")
```

i get this:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sty'`

i've looked around, other people who had this issue were told to either update their python since sty require python 3, or to run "pip install sty".

I'm running 3.10 so the first one is out i think.

For the second don't know what they mean by "pip install sty", i tried running it on python.exe but i get `"SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?"`

I tried installing sty with pycharm ( i offered to do it when i hovered the mouse over the import line), result: when i run the code on pycharm it does creates the pixels but console command still gives me the error (and that's where i'm suppoed to make it work)

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: What error do you get when you execute the program after installing sty?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay, the problem has been fixed. for some reason i had two python installed under different discs and i was thus using the wrong pip when trying to install sty. i fixed it by changing the path to pip under windows variable to the other one and now it works. 
sorry i didn't see your answer until now, it's my first time using stack overflow.